# git does not ignore a folder that used to be tracked

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory in my git repo that is in `.gitignore` but didn't use to be. The `.gitignore` entry is

```
**/bin/
```

Running `git rm --cached` does not work, it just gives me

```
fatal: pathspec 'bin/' did not match any files
```

I mention `git rm --cached` because that is what I ran to stop the contents of the directory from appearing in `git status`.

Running `git status` tells me that `bin/` is untracked, so it's not ignored.

Comment: If `git status` shows it as untracked, how have you determined that it is still tracked?

Comment: It might help if you show us `git status` and the directory that should be ignored.

Comment: @hvd you are correct, my question was wrong. I re-worded it.

Comment: Well, if the directory is indeed untracked, that explains why `git rm --cached` doesn't work. When I try this in a test repository, the exact entry that you used has the effect you want for me. Can you come up with a few short instructions to create a test repository that has the problem you describe?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The recursive syntax `**/bin/` in `.gitignore` only works in git 1.8 and higher, but I was unknowingly running 1.7.x. Updated git and everything is behaving as expected.